# How does the Doctor’s screwdriver run a calculation whilst destroyed?

Tags: doctor-who, the-day-of-the-doctor

In [The Almost People](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Almost_People), and [The Eleventh Hour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Eleventh_Hour_%28Doctor_Who%29), the Doctor's screwdriver is destroyed and later regenerated. However, in [The Day of the Doctor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_of_the_doctor), the Doctor(s), run a calculation running over 400 years.

How is this possible, if the screwdriver was destroyed between the start and finish?

Comment: They follow best practices and make off-site backups of all important data every day, including all the intermediate results of that calculation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is technically trivial. Anyone running a very long computation
(and some real computations can last for weeks) will regularly save
the state of the computation on some reliable medium that does not
need power, so that the computation can be restarted after any kind of
failure. Actually there can even be several levels of back-up,
balancing reliability and cost.

The computation does not need to be restarted with exactly the same
software, as long as the intermediate results that have been saved can
be interpreted and reused by the new software. Actually this can even
be a way to improve the software (or the hardware) while the
computation is on-going.  This is standard technology, even for people
who are not time-lords.

The screwdriver could simply save its state on the Tardis whenever
there are close enough to communicate by whatever means. It could also
be saved in various places known to be stable in time by someone who
travels through time.

If the screwdriver is destroyed, only that part of the computation
done since the last back-up is lost and must be redone.

By the way, since the Doctor travels through time, he could well
organize the computation and back-up to get a lot more than 400 years
worth of computation, depending on the structure of the algorithm and
the computational capacity of the screwdriver.

It is to be expected that the computation does not take all the
computational power of the screwdriver. If a computational thread
actually leaves a lot of untapped computational power, it can be
parallelized with a future fragment of the same thread by getting from
the future the starting state for the later thread. Time travel
extends the possibilities for parallelizing computations.

Comment: It might seem like the Doctor could have left his screwdriver running a calcuation somewhere safe, and jumped forward in time with the Tadis to complete any arbitary number of years instantly. However, as we know whenever he travels in the Tadis he encounters some alien plot to destabilise something, and so its very likely his screwdriver would have been stolen / turned into an evil sonic beast if left unattended...

Comment: If left unattended for aeons, the screwdriver could run into problems
at any time, with nothing to save the computation state. Furthermore,
it seems that it is implicit that the Doctor will never travel without
his screwdriver if he can help it. Hence I made the assumption that
the screwdriver age is the same as the doctor's age, about 400 years
in the episode I saw when the current doctor meets the (first ?) one
in existence when Gallifrey is about to be destroyed. Still, that may
leave room for longer computations. Other point is I am not sure the screwdriver can work without the Doctor (?).

Comment: @babou i really like the point that the screwdriver may need the doctor to operate. thank you very much!

Comment: More to the point, the screwdriver probably requires the tardis to operate, and it could be argued that the screwdriver is simply an extension of the tardis itself.  The screwdriver itself is actually much older than the doctor, having gone the long way around from roman times to modern day in the pandorica, but all that time there was neither a doctor nor a tardis.

Comment: I would like to point out that in The Big Bang the Doctor leaves his screwdriver in Amy's pocket for about 2000 years, and it was running the computation the entire time.

Comment: @childcat15 The Pandorica is a very special device. Is there any evidence that the screwdriver is actually
active in the Pandorica ? That would of course raise further possibilities.

Comment: @childcat15: In fairness, they did then reboot the entire universe. I'm not sure there are many backup strategies designed to maintain data integrity in that scenario.

Comment: When it back up to the Tradis, why wouldn't the calculation be routed to the more powerful computers in the Tradis and transferred back to the sonic?

Answer (score 7):

Like Rose said in The Day of The Doctor

" Same Software different case"

Therefore the Doctor's screwdriver was not completely destroyed, only the case containing it was; the software was safe making it possible for the TARDIS to repair the case and give the Doctor a seemingly "new" screwdriver with the computation still intact.

Answer (score 2):

In "Let's Kill Hitler", it's explained that instead of having settings, this version operates through a telepathic interface, linked to the Doctor.  Hence he can use it to do such a varied number of things without needing to continually change settings on it.

**WARNING GUESSWORK***

Therefore the internal state of the screwdriver is probably stored in the Tardis (on the cloud) as this is telepathically linked to the Dr. too.  When it is regenerates it just syncs and carries on without minor disruption.

Comment: please cite a source for the first bit.

Comment: In "Let's Kill Hitler", it's explained that instead of having settings, this version operates through a psychic interface, basically doing whatever the user thinks of while pointing and holding down the button.